# Matlab binary file does not accept its input values in shell

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, binaryfiles

I have compiled my Matlab function and am trying to run the resulting binary executable in a shell script (I am sure about my conversion). In Matlab, I run `My_function` script by:

```
names_ct{1}  = './file_ct_1';
names_ct{2}  = './file_ct_2';
names_mk{1}  = './file_mk_1';
names_mk{2}  = './file_mk_2';

My_function(names_ct, names_mk, 0);
```

However, when I run the compiled binary by using the following command in shell script, then I get an error.

```
My_function ./file_ct_1 ./file_ct_2 ./file_mk_1 ./file_mk_2 0
```

The error is:

```
Error using My_function
Too many input arguments.
MATLAB:TooManyInputs
Error: Too many input arguments.
ERROR My_function ./file_ct_1 ./file_ct_2 ./file_mk_1 ./file_mk_2 0
```

Anyone knows what is goin on?

Answer (score 0):

Your function only accepts three arguments and you are giving it five.
Can you avoid using cell array and create a separate variable for each element.
For example :

```
names_ct1  = './file_ct_1';
names_ct2  = './file_ct_2';
names_mk1  = './file_mk_1';
names_mk2  = './file_mk_2';
My_function(names_ct1 ,names_ct2, names_mk1, names_mk2, 0);
```

Comment: No, I can not do that because the number of inputs are variable. That is why I use cell. I can run Matlab script successfully but I can NOT run the binary version!

Comment: I do not know much about the compilation aspect but you may use 'varargin' syntax in order to have number of arguments variable. ex : My_function( varargin )

Answer (score 0):

Each of the command line arguments are passed as stings to your function. You cannot pass a cell array, nor numeric arrays, nor anything else. You need to write your function to take string input arguments.

If you need a variable number of input arguments, declare your function with

```
function name(varargin)
```

(see [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html))

Then, within your function, `varargin` is a cell array that contains each of the input strings. `nargin` is equal to `numel(varargin)`, and gives the number of input arguments.

You can further use [`inputParser`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html) to simplify parsing input arguments, if you need e.g. a way to separate the two different type of input arguments you seem to need.